# In MySQL, can I use IF in INSERT context?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, conditional-statements

Like:

```
INSERT INTO `video_play_counts`
   (`id`,`video_id`,`date`,`count`,`created`,`modified`) 
VALUES 
   ("",1,"2016-12-01",26,"2016-12-03 17:51:53","2016-12-03 17:51:53") 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  `count` = GREATEST(`count`,VALUES(`count`)), 
  `modified` = IF(VALUES(`count`) > `count`,VALUES(`modified`),`modified`)
```

So, I have a unique key on `video_id` and `date` and when I make an UPDATE on this unique key, in the case that the new `count` value is bigger the existing one, I would like to also update the `modified` field accordingly. 
The `count` field updates as expected but the `modified` field does not get the new value in the case of an UPDATE.

Please note that I'm using this to do multiple insert/update in one query, just in this example it has only one set of values.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested, but i am nearly sure that you must switch the last 2 line of your query, so that you first set `modified` and the set `count`to VALUES(`count`), else count is set to the GREATEST and never greater `count`